# Wordpress access to the private posts for specific users

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a bit confused. By default, WordPress is showing 404 error, when someone is trying to open private post. Can I extend that logic a bit? I need to show that post for the specific user:

```
if ( show_post_to_the_user(get_current_user_id()) {
  // show this post
}
```

I've tried to use **the_content** filter, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
             When you call post in back end  then post status give both
             $args = array(
             'orderby'          => 'date',
             'order'            => 'DESC',
             'post_type'        => 'post',
             'post_status'      => 'publish,private',
             'posts_per_page' => 6,
               );
```

Comment: Yes, it is giving private and publish posts. I did it, but when you are trying to open this private post, WP give 404 error.